# Calling MVC Action From ngBlur Event

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, sitecore

I am trying to update a model property called `State.TransactionProcessingIds.EventInstanceName` from within a `nb-blur` directive by calling a controller's action method in C#.

The following is in my view:

```
<md-input-container>
<input name="EventInstanceId" type="text" ng-blur="$http.post('/InternalDonations/Test').success(function (data) { State.TransactionProcessingIds.EventInstanceName = data; });">
</md-input-container>
```

and I have the following controller and action method:

```
public class InternalDonationsController : Controller
{
    public string Test()
    {
        return "test123";
    }
}
```

The ngBlur event fires when the textbox loses focus, however when this happens, I can see that `State.TransactionProcessingIds.EventInstanceName` is not updated.

I have attached the debugger to SiteCore and put a breakpoint on the action method and can see that it never gets called.

There is a route defined for `/InternalDonations/Test` which is working.

How can I call the action method from within `ngBlur`?

Comment: What does the network monitor of your browser say? Do you see the request there?

Comment: @NineBerry There's no request there for /InternalDonations/Test

Comment: Try calling function on blur.

Comment: @SudhirOjha what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using $http service on template, create method & inside that make call to service. So update template to

```
<md-input-container>
    <input name="EventInstanceId" type="text" ng-blur="postTestData()">
</md-input-container>
```

In controller add that method as:

```
this.postTestData = function() {
    $http.post('/InternalDonations/Test', postData).then(function (data) { 
        State.TransactionProcessingIds.EventInstanceName = data; 
    });
}
```

Make sure you inject $http to controller, and also your service is up, 1st test that service with POST (or GET) method in Postman, or any other REST client.

Comment: Where do I put the this.postTestData = function() code? In a <script> block in the .cshtml file?

Comment: @Backwards_Dave inside controller of your angularjs app (front end code)